# Вырезать из изображения часть

Tags: php, изображения

Допустим, у нас было изображение размером `150x150px`

Мне нужно получить из него `120x120`, т.е. нужно убрать `15px` сверху, `15px` снизу, `15px` справа, `15px` слева.

Как такое можно сделать?

Пробовал использовать `imagecreatetruecolor`, `imagecreatefromjpeg` и `imagecopyresampled`. Получается так, что обрезаются все стороны, кроме верхней и левой.

Comment: `imagemagic`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как-то так?

```
$w=135;
$h=135;    
$x=15;   
$y=15;    
$filename="image.jpg";
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$src);
$org_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename); 
$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($w,$h);
imagecopy($new_image, $image, 0, 0, $x, $y, $w, $h);
imagejpeg($new_image);
```

Comment: а вообще и правда лучше imagemagic
http://php.net/manual/ru/imagick.cropimage.php