# Вырезать часть у изображения

Tags: php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div>
  <img src="https://sun1-20.userapi.com/impg/NcsNzOuQZsocRmUSFnMmD5emlvltIbTUuCylQw/POPj6-e_gM0.jpg?size=1280x854&quality=96&proxy=1&sign=6bdcfb7f1a653cfdf5d573d7fe2d4960&c_uniq_tag=rhtOo2LEdQgSAJVgw7h6vykbzpokIh2hH2_r8BZ3kaQ&type=album">
  <img src="https://sun1-28.userapi.com/impg/E4fG9M8Ynq3CrM_AeUwrpQBTbiuLZmL_8vyLuQ/stSbz_qT1zo.jpg?size=1280x853&quality=96&proxy=1&sign=8022a0b1de16a7283c39e4c540c903e8&c_uniq_tag=8DB-s6ETxCfD_rs6gTU2kXsxlRbbWTNfzjVBgOHYKC0&type=album">
  <img src="https://sun9-61.userapi.com/impg/8IZj2YniJe7yAWd2V8_nHmD1zswc8D_IQutJkw/2LUunqu4PFY.jpg?size=1080x1024&quality=96&proxy=1&sign=e42dfe169a907cd0a31630044673305b&c_uniq_tag=xicgUMjsvURSd6iseIKeX_QHQF8_UyZuoVzMA60tNpI&type=album">
</div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вырезать из изображения часть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/150472/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.img{
  width: 219px;
  height:146px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position:center center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="img" style="background-image: url(https://sun1-20.userapi.com/impg/NcsNzOuQZsocRmUSFnMmD5emlvltIbTUuCylQw/POPj6-e_gM0.jpg?size=1280x854&quality=96&proxy=1&sign=6bdcfb7f1a653cfdf5d573d7fe2d4960&c_uniq_tag=rhtOo2LEdQgSAJVgw7h6vykbzpokIh2hH2_r8BZ3kaQ&type=album)"></div>
  <div class="img" style="background-image: url(https://sun1-28.userapi.com/impg/E4fG9M8Ynq3CrM_AeUwrpQBTbiuLZmL_8vyLuQ/stSbz_qT1zo.jpg?size=1280x853&quality=96&proxy=1&sign=8022a0b1de16a7283c39e4c540c903e8&c_uniq_tag=8DB-s6ETxCfD_rs6gTU2kXsxlRbbWTNfzjVBgOHYKC0&type=album)"></div>
  <div class="img" style="background-image: url(https://sun9-61.userapi.com/impg/8IZj2YniJe7yAWd2V8_nHmD1zswc8D_IQutJkw/2LUunqu4PFY.jpg?size=1080x1024&quality=96&proxy=1&sign=e42dfe169a907cd0a31630044673305b&c_uniq_tag=xicgUMjsvURSd6iseIKeX_QHQF8_UyZuoVzMA60tNpI&type=album)"></div>  
</div>
```